# I cannot fix an error in a JSON settings file in VS code

Tags: json

I'm a learner programmer. I wanted to prevent the VS code from opening the previous projects / session. I entered its settings to prevent window restore. But I cannot change it because there is some kind of error. I run the JSON file through a JSON validator, just as I read somewhere (but I know nothing about JSON yet).

The validator found a mistake in the syntax of the first line. But I don't know how to fix it. For me it has the same pattern as other lines:

Error:

```
"diffEditor.wordWrap": "on",
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.fontSize": 16,
  "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
  "workbench.iconTheme": "Monokai Pro Icons",
  "todohighlight.defaultStyle": {},
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai Dimmed",
  "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {

    "html": {
        //if element created is more than 2, it will break to new line for each element
        "inline_break": 2,
    }
}
//  the message from the validator
Error: Parse error on line 1:
...diffEditor.wordWrap": "on","editor.word
-----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'
```

But it's not clear for me at all.

Comment: Please provide the whole file.

Comment: You missed {  - Should be "{ diffEditor.wordWrap": "on",

Comment: Serge it diidn't work. There's something wrong with the braces but I don't know JSON yet. Your solution doesn't fix the error. Also when I add a brace { before the quotation mark, another brace at the end of the code is underlined as an error.

Answer (score 0):

The two surrounding braces were missing:

```
{
    "diffEditor.wordWrap": "on",
     "editor.wordWrap": "on",
     "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
     "editor.formatOnSave": true,
     "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
     "editor.fontSize": 16,
     "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
     "workbench.iconTheme": "Monokai Pro Icons",
     "todohighlight.defaultStyle": {},
     "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai Dimmed",
     "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
        "html": {
            //if element created is more than 2, it will break to new line for each element
            "inline_break": 2,
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer. I managed to reset the JSON file in VS Code settings by simply deleting its content and by restarting the VS code.